# Phonegap + SQLite Joining

Tags: sqlite, join, cordova

I have two tables customer & home in a local database for a ipad application.

I have a SQL query

```
SELECT C.CustomerID AS 'CID', H.CustomerID AS 'HID', H.lotNumber AS 'lotNumber' FROM CustomerInformation C LEFT JOIN HomeInformation AS H ON ( H.CustomerID = C.CustomerID )
```

It returns the proper amount of records, and display my address data correctly. However, all the data in the HomeInformation table is null

```
CustomerID FirstName      HomeID   CusomterID  lotNumber
1          Josh           1        1           73824
2          Smith          2        2           54353
3          Chris          3        3           75342
4          Bob            4        4           42342
5          John           5        5           24342
```

I have tried to use INNER join, Cross Join, and Outer Join, but no records are returned.

Comment: Do the `CustomerID` values in the two tables really have the same values? And the same data type?

Comment: Miss match data type. Tnx